can anyone explain why the string input taken after integer input in java gives error
Why does attempting to take a string input after an integer input using Scanner in Java often result in unexpected behavior or errors? What are the underlying details of this problem?"
I encountered an issue while attempting to take input in Java, specifically when trying to take a string input after an integer input. It asks what steps were taken (presumably using Scanner), and what the expected behavior was compared to the actual outcome. This question seeks to understand the discrepancy between expectations and reality, likely to troubleshoot and resolve the issue effectively.

Without knowing the errors and the code, it is impossible to help. Please [edit] your question and add the relevant code and errors as properly formatted text.
